# Installing server os without a monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I found an old Pentium III Dell computer that I'd like to use as a dedicated server. I have the install CD for Ubuntu 11.04 server and I have previously confirmed that the essential components of the computer are functional with a bulky CRT monitor that I couldn't have carried away with the computer.

I've set my router to a static IP address which I have written down. Is there a way I can SSH into the server during install and get this server up and running without borrowing a monitor and keyboard? All I have with me is my netbook... Also, if the router is set to a static IP address, does this mean that I can only have one connected computer at a time? Will I have to do this at a coffee shop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible via the serial port.  You could try [this](http://www.hacom.net/kb/debian-installer-serial-console-support).  It's instructions on modifying a Debian installer to work over serial, but should work for Ubuntu as well as long as you use the "minimal" CD/DVD images that do not use a graphic installer (the installers for the "minimal" images are the same as Debian).

However, you will need:

- another computer or laptop with a serial port or USB to serial adapter
- PuTTY or similar working on the laptop/second computer
- a null modem cable (serial cable with both ends female) to connect the two

Unless you have null modem cables laying around this is likely less convenient than getting a keyboard and monitor.

I also just found that it seems that it is possible to [complete the install over SSH](http://princessleia.com/journal/?p=1357) but you need to be at the console with a working keyboard/monitor to start it.

To answer the second part of your question, routers have at least two IP addresses.

In the typical home or SOHO scenario, one address (the WAN) is set by your ISP via it's DHCP server, and the other address is the "router's IP address" set by you or the configuration default (usualy 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.254).  Changing the router's IP address doesn't really do much for what you are trying to do - you aren't trying to connect to the router, you're trying to connect to a machine behind it.  You are wanting to give this old computer a fixed IP address instead of an unpredictable one from your router - the technical term for this is a "reservation" and you might look in your router configuration for such an option - you need to know the MAC address of your system to use that, though.

Of course, a quick and dirty way to do something similar is look at your router's DHCP options and see the range of IP addresses it hands out - should be something like 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.100.  You can set the computer's IP address to something outside of this range, say, 192.168.0.111, and the router will likely still route it just fine.